# Extract image from PDF using .Net c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, extract

I want to extract images from PDF. Tried many solutions but still not getting solution. Help me out....Thanks in advance

Comment: @mlk is correct and if you do a simple Google search you will see that iTextSharp is the best tool for this case.

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to extract images from PDFs.

Here is a sample that shows how to extract all images from a PDF:

```
static void ExtractAllImages()
{
    string path = "";
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            string imageName = string.Format("image{0}", i);
            string imagePath = pdf.Images[i].Save(imageName);
        }
    }
}
```

The library won't resample images. It will save them exactly the same as in PDF.

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle, vendor of the library.

Comment: Note that this is a commercial product with a 30-day evaluation mode.  The cheapest license is currently $595, with pricing going presumably well beyond $2,000 for the most expensive privately negotiated unlimited option.  See pricing info here: http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/purchase.aspx

Comment: That's maybe why it only takes about 50% of all images